# Understanding dates and time zones in Swift. DatePicker gives a UTC format, will this display correctly for all users in different time zones?

Tags: swift, date, swiftui

I need some help understanding how dates and time zones work in Swift / SwiftUI.

I'm currently using the DatePicker component and selecting the range to be now to infinity. The DatePicker returns a date in UTC format and this date is saved to my database. When a user in another timezone views this date will it automatically be converted to the correct zone?

My date is essentially a countdown so this countdown should be the same for every user regardless of their timezone. I don't know if I need to do more conversions or if iOS is doing it for me.

Here is the sample code I'm playing around with:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var timeNow = Date.now.addingTimeInterval(3600)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Countdown ends in:")
            
            Text(timeNow, style: .timer)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .monospaced()
            
            DatePicker("Opens", selection: $timeNow, in: Date.now...)
                .labelsHidden()
            
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            UIDatePicker.appearance().minuteInterval = 15
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` is not associated with any timezone. It just represents an *instant* in time, i.e. n seconds since some predefined epoch. You see it *formatted* as a datetime in UTC when you `print` it out, but a `Date` is just a number of seconds.

Assuming the database doesn't do anything weird with the `Date` value (i.e. if the column's type also represents an *instant*), then all users will see the same count down when they fetch the same row from the database. Since this is a count down, there is no need to convert `Date`s in any way. All that needs to be done is to find the difference in seconds between now and the `Date`, and format that as a duration. Time zones are irrelevant here.

On the other hand, users in different timezones will obviously see different times selected in the date picker for the same `timeNow` value. `DatePicker` needs to display the year, month, day, hour, minute, and so on. To get these numbers, it needs to interpret the `Date` in some timezone. This is by default the user's timezone, but you can override this by changing the environment.

```
.environment(\.timeZone, someTimeZone)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. Swifts handy .timer style for the Text view is doing a lot of heavy lifting for me already. Got a better understanding now!